# How to run a psql metacommand in SQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

It's sometimes difficult or frustrating to fire up a raw `psql` client to a database, but I want to use the metacommands (or slash commands) like `\dn`, `\dt`, etc

Is there a way to execute these in other SQL clients?

Answer (score 1):

Meta commands never get sent to the server, they're actually interpreted and converted into SQL by the psql client, but you can get the postgres client to tell you the equivalent SQL.

Using `psql -E` to get psql to print out the SQL it creates.

So if you have a local database that's easier to connect to, you can connect to that to find the SQL equivalent of your command.

eg

```
# psql -E -h localhost -U postgres
psql (13.0, server 10.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dn
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1;
**************************
```

Comment: Alternatively you can enable printing of these queries by entering
`\set ECHO_HIDDEN true`
directly within psql repl and then disable after you no longer need it via
`\set ECHO_HIDDEN false`